# На странице Наша модель нет перевода текста ссылки на CoC

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка, нормы-поведения

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help тоже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]